# how to save data in xamarine firestore

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code :

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using firestore;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using Firebase;
using Java.Util;

namespace firestore
    {
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText phone;
    EditText password;
    Button save;
    FirebaseFirestore database;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        phone = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.phone);
        password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.password);
        save=  (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.save);


        save.Click += Save_Click;
        database = GetDatabase();
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.Put("phone",phone.Text);
        map.Put("password",password.Text);
        DocumentReference docref = database.Collection("users").Document();
        docref.Set(map);
    }

    public FirebaseFirestore GetDatabase()
    {
        FirebaseFirestore database;
        var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetProjectId("mohammed-682b7")
            .SetApplicationId("mohammed-682b7")
            .SetApiKey("AIzaSyC_atciyoeH0BMCD3rTTHPGtZa4EU1fu7k")
            .SetDatabaseUrl("https://mohammed-682b7.firebaseio.com")
            .SetStorageBucket("mohammed-682b7.appspot.com")
            .Build();
        var app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

        database = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);
        return database;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Java.Lang.RuntimeException: `<Timeout exceeded getting exception details>` occurred

I followed the explanation in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mneY6H0zMNE

this is the output:
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejp$zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/firestore.firestore-h-EYnpx7ZY1EvLUwpnKzoQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/firestore.firestore-h-EYnpx7ZY1EvLUwpnKzoQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/firestore.firestore-h-EYnpx7ZY1EvLUwpnKzoQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
12-16 20:08:22.896 E/AndroidRuntime(10311):     ... 20 more
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException:

Thread finished:  #5
The thread 0x5 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished:  #7
The thread 0x7 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished:  #4
The thread 0x4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished:  #6
The thread 0x6 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: you need to catch the exception and capture/print/log its details

Comment: In order to analyze the cause of this error, could you please post the full log of this error just as jason said?

Comment: thank you i edited the question to attach the output of the program

Comment: According to the error log you post,you can try to add nuget Xamarin.Google.Guava in your project, and try it again.

Comment: i added Xamarin.Google.Guava in my project

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use runtime database to achieve that, Here is running GIF.
[image]

Here is my code about save data to database.

```
 private void Save_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string firebaseURL = "https://fir-databasedemo-62a72.firebaseio.com/";
        var mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(firebaseURL).GetReference("fir-databasedemo-62a72");

        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
       string s= Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalMilliseconds).ToString();

        string username = "User" + s;

        var resp = mDatabase.Child(username);

        var resp2=   resp.SetValue("Phone");
        var resp3 = resp.SetValue("Password");
        resp = mDatabase.Child(username + "/Phone");
        resp.SetValue(phone.Text);

        resp = mDatabase.Child(username+"/Password");
        resp.SetValue(password.Text);

    }
```

Here is my demo.
https://github.com/851265601/FireBaseDatabaseDemoXA

Here is video about it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWajpCQZ7Z0