# How to upload nested model information to firestore in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I'm working in Xamarin.Forms using the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Firestore package, and I have a nested model like

```csh
public class Grow
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PlantName { get; set; }
    public List<Day> Days { get; set; }
}
public class Day
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string GrowId { get; set; }
    public string LightsOn { get; set; }
    public string LightsOff { get; set; }
    public List<Nutrient> Nutrients { get; set; }
}
public class Nutrient
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DayId { get; set; }
    public string NutrientName { get; set; }
    public double NutrientAmount { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm unsure how to structure this in Xamarin.iOS to upload, I'd like to upload it as a Dictionary. Should I use a `Dictionary<object, object>`? And how would I convert it to iOS specific code for the keys and values? I'm new to Xamarin, so sorry if this seems like a beginner question!
What I've tried is

```
public async Task<bool> InsertGrow(Grow grow)
{
    try
    {
        var keys = new NSObject[]
        {
            new NSString("plantName"),
            new NSObject(new NSString[] {
                new NSString("lightsOn"),
                new NSString("lightsOff"),
                new NSObject(new NSString[] {
                    new NSString("nutrientName"),
                    new NSString("nutrientAmount")
                })
           })
        }
    }
}
```

for the keys, but I don't think this is the right way, would it be better to treat each model as a separate Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I wouldn't store iOS specific objects when using Xamarin Forms. Just store regular c# strings and objects.

---

2. I failed to find any useful C# example of "nested objects" to/from, so starting a "community" answer with some links that might get you started.

> [Dotnet firestore sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/9055700d7cd4119aec8f801633ad0b63a76c0a6a/firestore/api/AddData/Program.cs#L104-L121).

Shows some useful techniques. Especially note attribute `[FirestoreProperty]` to put on properties that should be stored. HOWEVER doesn't show NESTED objects.

> The above sample was reached from [Add Data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#c_3).

Browse around those official Google docs. Note how they show code for different languages. At the right of each code snippet is `More` dropdown. `c#` is in that dropdown.

---

> [miyu's Plugin.CloudFirestore - see section "Data-Mapping"](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore#data-mapping).

I have seen mentions of this as making it easier to access firestore from C#.

> [Handling Nested Objects in firestore with flutter](https://mullr.dev/2020/07/05/handling-nested-objects-in-firestore-with-flutter/).

This isn't C#, its flutter (Dart language). It would be great if someone wrote a blog like that one, for C#. I mention it because it discusses the principles involved in nesting objects in firestore.

---

> [android - how to save data in xamarin firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346024/how-to-save-data-in-xamarine-firestore?rq=1).

Included this because of these two lines:

```
resp = mDatabase.Child(username + "/Phone");
resp.SetValue(phone.Text);
```

that fundamentally is what needs to happen to store a "key" and a corresponding "value". One way to build up a "dictionary" in firestore. In that case, the key is `username + "/Phone"`, and the value is `phone.Text`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up going with Plugin.Firestore and I'm able to at least see my index page with my test database entries. Still working on getting my detail view to work properly, but I do have database access using my user accounts in my app.